# LDA Topic Model Performance - Topic Coherence Implementation for scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I have a question around measuring/calculating topic coherence for LDA models built in scikit-learn.

Topic Coherence is a useful metric for measuring the human interpretability of a given LDA topic model. Gensim's [CoherenceModel](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/coherencemodel.html) allows Topic Coherence to be calculated for a given LDA model (several variants are included).

I am interested in leveraging [scikit-learn's LDA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html) rather than [gensim's LDA](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) for ease of use and documentation (*note: I would like to avoid using the gensim to scikit-learn wrapper i.e. actually leverage sklearn’s LDA*). From my research, there is seemingly no scikit-learn equivalent to Gensim’s CoherenceModel.

Is there a way to either:

**1** - Feed scikit-learn’s LDA model into gensim’s CoherenceModel pipeline, either through manually converting the scikit-learn model into gensim format or through a scikit-learn to gensim wrapper (I have seen the wrapper the other way around) to generate Topic Coherence?

Or

**2** - Manually calculate topic coherence from scikit-learn’s LDA model and CountVectorizer/Tfidf matrices?

I have done quite a bit of research on implementations for this use case online but haven’t seen any solutions. The only leads I have are the documented equations from scientific literature.

If anyone has any knowledge on any similar implementations, or if you could point me in the right direction for creating a manual method for this, that would be great. Thank you!

*Side note: I understand that perplexity and log-likelihood are available in scikit-learn for performance measurements, but these are not as predictive from what I have read.

Comment: I don't have any direct answer to your question. However, why don't you just use gensim to fit a new LDA model? I have no experience with LDA in scikit-learn, but I do know that gensim is blazing fast and nice to use

Comment: Honestly Gensim's own LDA is not so fast when corpus gets really large and you ask for 50+ topics. It also tends to have poorer results than those of i.e MALLET. I have the same question with the author.

Comment: In case you have found this question, you should have a look into tmtoolkit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613532/how-do-i-calculate-the-coherence-score-of-an-sklearn-lda-model

Answer (score 3):

**Feed scikit-learn’s LDA model into gensim’s CoherenceModel pipeline**

As far as I know, there is no "easy way" to do this. You would have to manually reformat the sklearn data structures to be compatible with gensim. I haven't attempted this myself, but this strikes me as an unnecessary step that might take a long time. There is an old Python 2.7 attempt at a [gensim-sklearn-wrapper](https://github.com/StevenReitsma/gensim-sklearn-wrapper) which you might want to look at, but it seems deprecated - maybe you can get some information/inspiration from that.

**Manually calculate topic coherence from scikit-learn’s LDA model and CountVectorizer/Tfidf matrices?**

The summing-up of vectors you need can be easily achieved with a loop. You can find code samples for a "manual" [coherence calculation for NMF](https://github.com/derekgreene/topic-model-tutorial/blob/master/3%20-%20Parameter%20Selection%20for%20NMF.ipynb). Calculation depends on the specific measure, of course, but sklearn should return you the data you need for the analysis pretty easily.

**Resources**

It is unclear to me why you would categorically exclude gensim - the topic coherence pipeline is pretty extensive, and documentation exists.

See, for example, these three tutorials (in Jupyter notebooks).

- [Demonstration of the topic coherence pipeline in Gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/topic_coherence_tutorial.ipynb)
- [Performing Model Selection Using Topic Coherence](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/topic_coherence_model_selection.ipynb)
- [Benchmark testing of coherence pipeline on Movies dataset](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/topic_coherence-movies.ipynb)

The formulas for several coherence measures can be found in this paper [here](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D12-1087).